# Help with searchform with GET

Tags: php

OK

If im on: `index.php?area=characters`

and type in eg. `Agamemnon Busmalis` in the search field:

```
<h2>Search Character</h2>
<form action="?area=characters" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```

I want it do send me to : `index.php?area=characters&name=Agamemnon+Busmalis`

but instead it sends me to: index.php?name=Agamemnon+Busmalis

why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hidden form element:

```
 <h2>Search Character</h2>
 <form  method="get">
 Name: <input type="text" action="form.html" name="name" />
 <input type="hidden" name="area" value="characters" />
 </form>
```

Comment: nooo dont work the parameters switch places look: index.php?name=tony&area=characters

Comment: Maybe you should check the syntax. Action is an attribute of form, not input

Comment: Your comment is unclear. What didn't work? Are you concerned about the order of the get params? Did the name get truncated?

Comment: They'll show up in whatever order you define them.  Move the hidden field above visible one.